# A code coverage tool running on Jenkins

Tags: c++, jenkins, code-coverage, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to research a C++ code coverage tool running on Jenkins framework. Could you please introduce any tools?

Comment: your OS were you developing?

Comment: Developing on gcc/Linux/Windows. Could you have any ideas for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have successfully used Parasoft with Jenkins.

Comment: Are there any document how to or any things else support easy to use?

Answer (score 5):

You can use GCOV + LCOV for calc your code coverage. Gcov for generate all info, lcov for generate result(html). For public HTML use standard post-build action "Publish HTML"

GCOV: [link](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Gcov-and-Optimization.html#Gcov-and-Optimization)

LCOV: [link](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php)

P.S. It's all for Linux.